# Cannot write to mounted samba share via proftpd

Tags: permissions, samba, proftpd

Was hoping I could be pointed in the correct direction with this. I have googled and searched but nothing has turned up helpful.

I basically have 2 VMs, one a samba server and one an ftp server using proftpd.
The ftp server has a mounted samba share from the samba server, and no ftp user can write to it except root.

What sort of permissions are required here? Ive tried all sorts of combinations on both VMs using root:root or "username":"username" (then obviously use that username to try and write), Ive tried 777 permissions and cant come right.

Am I perhaps missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE:

On samba server the path being shared is /data/listing
On ftp server, the above is mounted at /resource01

Permissions are currently root:root and 777

My issue is, with the above scenario, shouldnt it be as simple as putting a ftp account under the root group, and then they should have right access? Because that doesnt work..

Comment: Whats the path to mounted folder ? Who's the owner of that folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777` to your samba mount:

```
mount -t cifs //sambaVM/data/listing /resource01 -o guest,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

Add `username=` and `password=` options instead `guest` if needed.

Check permissions on /resource01 before and after mounting samba share. They can vary.

Check your FTP configuration by writing to /resource01 without samba mounted.

Comment: Thanks. The need for the user to write to this share fell away If anyone who has the same issue can try this and post back that would be great